# tensorflow DuplicateFlagError: The flag 'dataset' is defined twice

Tags: python, tensorflow

my major is chemistry

so I want to use this github file.

https://github.com/alexarnimueller/SMILES_generator

but when I ran the train.py file, I met this error.

> DuplicateFlagError: The flag 'dataset' is defined twice. First from C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py, Second from C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py.  Description from first occurrence: dataset file containing smiles strings

What should I do?

Please solve my problem....

Comment: how do you run the training file? did you use the example command or something different? may help if you added such detail

Comment: I tried it with python 2.7, ran the same command as in examples with changing the data path, and it entered training phase successfully